# Python infinite loop I tried with while but no luck

Tags: python

hi guys im new at coding im trying to create an infinite loop in the follow code

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api, win32con
import sys 

time.sleep (2)

color = (255, 255, 255)
a = pyautogui.screenshot()

for x in range(a.width):
    for y in range(a.height):
        if a.getpixel((x, y)) == (119,  44,  44):            
            pyautogui.click(x, y)
            time.sleep(2)
            pyautogui.click(3050, 1411)
            time.sleep(35)
            a = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

I tried with while but no luck, can someone help me please?
Thanks for the attention and have a nice day(=

Comment: What are you trying to make infinite?

Comment: There's no `while` loop in that code. It's helpful to show what you tried but *isn't* working.

Comment: Why do you think you want an infinite loop?  Strictly speaking, such animals are usually best avoided.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make infinite loop just use

```
while True:
    # Add your code
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

Include **while True:** wherever you are trying to include an infinite loop.
I am not sure exactly where you are trying to introduce one but my best guess is you are trying to introduce here :

**if a.getpixel((x, y)) == (119,  44,  44):**

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import random
import win32api, win32con
import sys 

time.sleep (2)

color = (255, 255, 255)

a = pyautogui.screenshot()

for x in range(a.width):
    for y in range(a.height):
        if a.getpixel((x, y)) == (119,  44,  44):
            while True: 
                pyautogui.click(x, y)
                time.sleep(2)
                pyautogui.click(3050, 1411)
                time.sleep(35)
                a = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

Comment: If this were what the OP was looking for, why include the two `for` loops at all?  Why not then just `x = 0; y = 0; ...`?  My guess is that they're thinking to have their entire code run indefinitely (as @flavio's answer suggests).  It's impossible to know for sure, but that makes more sense than what you propose.